# Server Signature displaying even after config change

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, centos7

I am working on Apache 2.4, i want to make Server Signature off, so that when i get a error in the application it won't print all the information of the server. So, i added below lines of code

```
ServerSignature off
ServerTokens Prod
```

I added the above lines at the end of httpd.conf file. Even then when i get the error in the application i can see the server information on the page.

update: Please find the attached screen shot of configuration i added at end of file and also the error

Any solutions or suggestions are totally welcome.

Thanks

[Apache Server Information when resource not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VULFf.png)

[Configuration in httpd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlQcu.png)

Comment: I suggest adding more of your config along with a screenshot showing the error page.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you added it at httpd.conf. Try to see if its declared otherwise in some other configs, like conf-enabled/security.conf.

Having these things declared multiple times on a global setting would confuse the server.

Comment: No they are declared multiple times, only in httpd.conf and that too at the end of the file i declared those